# Is there a compact complex surface $X$ with $c_2(X)=7+6n$ and $c_1^2(X)=17+18n$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

As stated in [1], most pairs of positive integers $c_1^2$, $c_2$ satisfying $c_1^2+c_2=0$ $\mod 12$, the [BMY inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogomolov%E2%80%93Miyaoka%E2%80%93Yau_inequality) and the [Noether inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_inequality) are actually Chern numbers of compact complex surfaces, except for some points $(c_1^2, c_2)$ near the BMY line $c_1^2=3c_2$.

To state the construction: Find a ball quotient $X$ (compact complex surface with $c_1^2=3c_2$) that is a fibration $X \rightarrow C$, do base changing $\tilde C \rightarrow C$ and introduce ramifications in $\tilde C$, then twist the fibers in the pullback $X \times_C \tilde C$.

The major limitation of his construction lies in $X$, as there're no ways to move the point towards the BMY line or even along the direction $(3,1)$.

If we let $X$ be [Cartwright-Steger surfaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1631073X09003987)(a kind of ball quotient that completely fills the BMY line), it's possible ([2], Theorem 1.4) to apply base changings but not fiber twisting ($X$ lacks base-stabilizing automorphisms as required in [1]), and the closest-to-BMY unsolved case is $(c_1^2,c_2)=(17+18n,7+6n)$ for nonnegative integers $n$.

**Question:** Is there a construction of such a surface for even a single $n$?

[1] Chen, Zhijie. "The existence of algebraic surfaces with preassigned Chern numbers." Mathematische Zeitschrift 206.1 (1991): 241-254.

[2] Vidussi, Stefano. "The slope of surfaces with Albanese dimension one." arXiv preprint arXiv:1706.02396 (2017).